# Компиляция кода на С(Си)

Tags: c++, c

Oc - Windows 7 x64. 
 Установил компилятор MinGW(GNU). Установил текстовый редактор Notepad++.
Как скомпилировать код написанный в редакторе?

Вызываю командную строку(cmd). Что писать там дальше?

Comment: `g++ *.cpp -o program.exe`? Это если зависимостей нет.

Comment: а так вообще почитайте вывод `g++ --help`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcc -o hello.exe hello.c
```

Программа `hello.c` компилируется в исполняемый файл `hello.exe`.